# Apache HttpClient. Время ожидания ответа

Tags: java, apache, http

Использую org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient 4.5.2.

Создаю объект таким образом:

```
httpClient = HttpClients.custom() ... .build();
```

Выполняю запрос так:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http:// example .com/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet));
```

Бывает так, что ответа нет 2-3 минуты, кончается терпение, перезапускаю программу.

Вопрос: Каким образом можно задать время ожидания ответа, например 15 секунд, по истечении которых response присваивался null и программа идет дальше?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
RequestConfig globalConfig =
   RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(15000).build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
   HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).build();
```

setSocketTimeout указываем в миллисекундах. Если ответа нет более 15 секунд получаем исключение

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out...

Ловим исключение и реагируем как это необходимо в конкретной ситуации (повтор запроса, запись в лог и т.д.).

P.S. Буду рад услышать другие варианты, если такие есть, от опытных людей. Бывает что мой код работает, но более продвинутые разработчики говорят мне что "так писать нельзя".